# Proguard, do not obfuscate gradle jars

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I have a problem with joda-time when I run my android app :

```
java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "org/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap"
```

It's because proguard seems to change the name or obfuscate the resource file named ZoneInfoMap in the joda-time jar file.

In my config, I have :

```
-adaptresourcefilenames
-adaptresourcefilecontents
-keeppackagenames org.joda.time.**
-keep public class org.joda.time.** {public private protected *;}
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
```

I've read that we can add

```
-libraryjars my.jar
```

BUT, I don't know where is located my jars with gradle (gradle choose itself, and create its own folders...)

What can I do to run my app without error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not proguard problem. It's gradle setting problem.

in gradle build, the resources files in 'src' will not be included in final library or application.
so, you  should create 'resources' folder in your sourceSet(main or androidTest) and move the resources files(org/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap) to that directory.

it will solve your problem.